# Input with Dropdown as label, overflowing the screen. How to make it responsive?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am working on Semantic UI with React.
I have the issue where dropdown fields are quite large, and I need to break them in multiple lines. But instead of breaking it into lines it overflows from the screen.

```
const options = [
  { key: ".comwewfwfwf", text: ".comwr2u3rbirubiubiubib", value: ".com" },
  { key: ".net", text: ".netpojpj0w9jefwfbwiofbw", value: ".net" },
  { key: ".org", text: ".orgwoefifoifoioiwoifwoicnwoinwonwo", value: ".org" }
];
const App = () => (
  <Input
    label={
      <Dropdown
        className="cdd"
        direction="left"
        placeholder="Select Currency"
        search
        options={options}
      />
    }
    labelPosition="right"
    direction="right"
    placeholder="Your Deposit"
    value={1}
  />
);
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a codepen or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The Label in that context has text that will display and expand the Label itself to fill the width. The text will not wrap, even with spaces. If you want to do something where the selected text wraps to a new line in the Dropdown label, you will need to add some of your own custom CSS to do this.

I'd recommend setting a `max-width` to make sure that even long text does not break out. You then have some options. Either keep the text on one line and use CSS to add an ellipsis for overflowing text, or you can set the text display to add hyphens or to different break properties.

This is all custom CSS and not a function of Semantic UI React or how the Semantic UI styles work out of the box.